# Bamboo + Git Azure DevOps = "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.". For Git Submodule

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules, bamboo

I try to checkout in Bamboo from Git repository in DevOpsAzure and see next:

```
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:55    Submodule '***' (***) registered for path '***'
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:55    Cloning into '***'...
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:55    Warning: Permanently added 'vs-ssh.visualstudio.com,**IP**' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:56    remote: Public key authentication failed.
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:56    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:56    
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:56    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
simple  18-Jul-2020 15:11:56    and the repository exists.
```

[image]

Submodule configured as ssh path.
Base git-repository and git-submodule-repository location at same DevOps Azure.

I see Base git-repository checkout is OK, but git-submodule is not OK.

Where is my wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) on azure devops and set up a repo on Bamboo like this:

Authentication type: None

```
https://<token>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_git/<repository>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution.